# Why is ElasticSearch index searchable when refresh_interval is set to -1 on initial data upload?

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, refresh

I'm performing a large upload of data to an empty index.

This [article](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/tune-for-indexing-speed.html) suggests to set "refresh_interval=-1" and "number_of_replicas=0" to increase upload performance. Then it says to enable it back.

The interesting thing is that if I don't enable it back - I can still send the queries to the newly created index and get the results.

I'd like to know why is that and what I got wrong ? (My expectation was that I should get zero results because indexing is disabled)

And one more thing I'd like to understand - if I enable refresh_interval back to the original value, do I need to execute /_refresh operation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By default, Elasticsearch periodically refreshes indices every second,
> but only on indices that have received one search request or more in
> the last 30 seconds. You can change this default interval using the
> index.refresh_interval setting.

so document says: when you send a search request, it will send a refresh request with that. so you could search your data but very slow for first time or miss some data for first search. it is better to have a refresh_interval if you index new data on your indices.

Comment: Do I get this right that if nobody queries this index during upload I don't even have to disable all of this ? However I should probably disable replication...

Comment: @ievgen if you need very fast indexing, you could/should disable refresh_interval but if you have search request during indexing, it doesn't matter if you disable or not.